# css ellipsis not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, ellipsis

[text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664195/text-overflowellipsis-doesnt-work-on-ie)  DOESNT SOLVE THE PROBLEM HERE. In this case `-ms-text-overflow` doesn't apply the ellipsis here.

Ellipsis not working in IE8 and 9. It seems `-ms-text-overflow` property is not doing anything.

```
<div class="client">
  <span class="client-name">Some Client Long Name</span>
</div>

.client {
  display: block !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  width: 170px !important;
  overflow: hidden;         
  word-wrap: normal !important;         
  float:left;    
  padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.client-name {
  color: #AFAFAF;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664195/text-overflowellipsis-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257991/cannot-get-ellipsis-on-a-link-text-in-ie9-and-ie8

Comment: what's duplicated?, i've already read that post and it used the -ms-text-overflow property too.

Comment: you should apply the text-overflow to the span to be coherent. of course some css has to migrate down to it ... just keep the float for .client rest goes to the span

Comment: GCyrillus, i'm sorry you were right, i've kept only the float and width in client, it works correct now in IE. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In this link is answer, for me worked like a charm in IE9:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13260224/1064818

Rule above is correct

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE8:

```
.client {
  float:left; 
  padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px;  
  width: 170px !important;
}

.client-name {
  display: block !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;           
  overflow: hidden;         
  word-wrap: normal !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  color: #AFAFAF;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```